# iPhone: Where can I find those arrow icons used on the toolbar of the Photo Library (Camera Roll)

Tags: iphone, icons, toolbar

I am looking for those arrow icons (a left white arrow and a white right arrow) that are used on the lower toolbar of the Photo Library (or Camera Roll).  I also have seen them on the Facebook app and some other custom apps.  I am surprised that they are not built in "UIBarButtonSystemItem" icons.  Can anybody point me to these icons?

Answer (score 5):

They are built-in UIBarButtonSystemItem — [private ones](http://www.iphonedevwiki.net/index.php?title=UIBarButtonItem). Specifically, values of 107 and 108.

Other custom apps create their own arrows, and this is what you should do for AppStore apps.

Comment: Brilliant. This is so helpful, thanks so much.  No wonder I coudldn't find these, as they are "undocumented" and I have to use the #.

Comment: @Phamer: Be aware that using the undocumented APIs could get your app rejected from the app store.

Answer (score 4):

The icon set here seems to include the left/right arrows:

http://blog.twg.ca/2009/09/free-iphone-toolbar-icons/

and also has retina display versions here:

http://blog.twg.ca/2010/11/retina-display-icon-set/

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any good ones, so I made a set; you can grab them [here](http://www.conormulligan.com/blog/2010/07/16/iphone-arrow-icons). There are eight icons included: up, down, left and right, all in both standard and high-resolutions.